# SVM on OpenCV Mat Error (train data must be floating-point matrix)

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, libsvm

i'm trying to do a training using OpenCV and SVM.
But i have a problem, precisely this error:

```
 OpenCV Error: Bad argument (train data must be floating-point matrix) in cvCheckTrainData
```

I have to do a train in a dataSet of images where every images has 68 point (X,Y) that i use to do SVM.

In the beginning this was my code :

```
//for each image
fin_land.open(str_app); assert(fin_land);
for (int i=(0+(68*count_FOR)); i<(num_landCKplus+(68*count_FOR)); i++) {
    fin_land >> f1;
    fin_land >> f2;
    int data[2] = {(int)f1, (int)f2};
    Mat actual(1, 2, CV_32FC1, &data);
    trainData.push_back(actual);
}
// SVM
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type    = CvSVM::NU_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::POLY;     
trainData = trainData.reshape(1, #numImage);
SVM.train(trainData, trainLabels, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

The problem with this code was that i thought to use a Mat for the test with 68 row and 2 columns, because every training-class in my SVM has 2 columns, but i received this error :

```
OpenCV Error: Incorrect size of input array (Input sample must be 1-dimensional vector) in cvPreparePredictData
```

If I have correctly understood, the problem was that the dimension of the test Mat need to be only one dimensional. So, i thought to modify my code like this:

```
//for each image
fin_land.open(str_app); assert(fin_land);
for (int i=(0+(68*count_FOR)); i<(num_landCKplus+(68*count_FOR)); i++) {
    fin_land >> f1;
    fin_land >> f1;
    int data = (int)f1;
    trainData.push_back(&data);
    data = (int)f2;
    trainData.push_back(&data);
}
```

Now every training-class has only one column, so even the Mat of test, but I have a new error and it says:

```
 OpenCV Error: Bad argument (train data must be floating-point matrix) in cvCheckTrainData
```

The problem is that the type of the new mat of trainingSet is wrong?
I don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you need float data (and integer labels)
- 1 row per feature, 1 label per row.

---

```
float f1,f2;
for (int i=(0+(68*count_FOR)); i<(num_landCKplus+(68*count_FOR)); i++) {
    fin_land >> f1;
    fin_land >> f1;
    trainData.push_back(f1); // pushing the 1st thing will determine the type of trainData
    trainData.push_back(f2);
}

trainData = trainData.reshape(1, numItems);
SVM.train(trainData, trainLabels, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

Comment: thank you.. seems to be ok .. but now I get stuck on training, without returning any error ... I tried to wait, but with a training  matrix of 582 * 544 it seems strange that it takes so long ... it's possible that it's an overfitting problem?